# Preferring an implicit conversion over another

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

I got in a situation where I have a number of pair of classes, which I'll call `Legacy` and `Modern`, which have converting constructors from the same types.

```
struct Legacy { Legacy(int); };
struct Modern { Modern(int); };
```

Potentially, even templated constructors:

```
struct Legacy { template <typename T> Legacy(T); };
struct Modern { template <typename T> Modern(T); };
```

Similarly, there's a number of functions overloaded on those types:

```
void f(Legacy) { ... }
void f(Modern) { ... }
```

Is there a way to modify `Legacy` and `Modern`'s constructors in a way that `Modern`'s is always preferred for implicit conversions?

```
f(42); // should call f(Modern(42))
```

[over.ics.user] doesn't seem to allow for any ranking in implicit conversions involving user-defined conversions (in other words the call is ambiguous, and that's it), but maybe I'm overlooking something.

Comment: And you are using both modern and legacy in parallel? Something like `struct Demo { Legacy l; Modern m; };` (well, maybe not *as* close as in this example, but still within the same compilation unit)?

Comment: Make them all `explicit`. Single argument implicit conversions have been found to be a source of unexpected errors.  Have a read of: https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rc-explicit

Comment: In these cases, I want them implicit. (E.g. two different string classes, constructors from `char*`). Also, marking them _all_ `explicit` wouldn't solve much? You'd still need to specify the conversion you want at call site, so basically solving the problem above in the same way as you would by having implicit conversion.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is to make `Legacy`'s constructor explicit. This should have the same end-effect as a ranking because even if you had "ranked" implicit constructors the only way to call `Legacy`'s is to explicitly call it.

That said, converting constructors can be a source of confusion and bugs so you might consider making BOTH of them explicit.

Comment: That would however be a source-incompatible change; there's simply too much code using the Legacy's implicit conversion. (And, similarly, would break the implicit conversions for the "modern" functions only taking a Modern.)